# How can I set my first button as initially selected when a user jumps into the view?

Tags: swift

I want my first button to be initially selected when a user select a project. Right now you have to click on the first button to trigger it. Instead of clicking on it at the beginning I want to initially select it when a user jumps into a view.

How can I select my firstButton as initially selected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an outlet for it then inside `viewDidLoad`

```
var fButton = buttons.first!

fButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.orange, for: .normal)
```

**OR**

```
onTapChangeColor(fButton)
```

---

```
@IBAction func onTapChangeColor(_ sender: UIButton) {
    buttons.forEach { 
        $0.setTitleColor( $0 == sender ? .orange : .white, for: .normal)
    }
}
```

Comment: then toggle it's `isHideen` property ?

Comment: you can initially add the subview with `planAction(fButton)` also in `viewDidLoad`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of changing the `titleColor` everytime a `button` is tapped, you can simply set the `color` of each `button` in the `collection` as per their state - **`.selected or .normal`**.

Also, only change the `button's` `isSelected` to `true/false` everytime - either a `button` is tapped, or when you select a `button` initially.

```
class VC: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet var buttons: [UIButton]!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        buttons.forEach {
            $0.setTitleColor(.orange, for: .selected)
            $0.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
        }
        buttons.first?.isSelected = true
    }

    @IBAction func onTapChangeColor(_ sender: UIButton) {
        buttons.forEach {
            $0.isSelected = ($0 == sender)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Didn't get you. Please clarify the requirement a bit more.

Comment: Do you want to add different subviews for all the buttons?